# Online/Offline Connection Redirect PhoneGap/Cardova?

Tags: javascript, networking, redirect, cordova, offline

I'm developing an app using PhoneGap/Cordova 3.3.x and I'm not having any luck with a script that can check if a connection is available, and if so display the "main.html". If no connection, display "offline.html". Right now my index.html currently redirects to my "main.html" and I have this script in the "index.html" although its not working..I've tried several other scripts to no avail. Let me know if I need to have an appropriate .js file also, I am aware with older phonegap builds you used to have to contain a phonegap.js file in the assets?.. Any help? ::

```
<script>
function checkConnection() {
var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

var states = {};
states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';
}
  if (networkState == Connection.NONE ){
   window.location = "offline.html";
   } 
            }
        }

 window.location='./main.html';
</script>
```

*I've also tried "./offline" which only gave me the default android page is not available.* 
Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: I wanted to add that I am experimenting on the Android platform, but the app will be deployed on all 3build options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to two events in your onLoad (same place as your deviceready).

The two events are "online" and "offline":

```
document.addEventListener("offline", this.onReceivedOffline, false);
document.addEventListener("online", this.onReceivedOnline, false);
```

So it will be

```
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
function onOffline()
{
    window.location = "offline.html";
}
```

You can read more about it here:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#online

Comment: For some reason I'm not having any luck, I've posted another question below if you have any idea why that wouldn't be working? Originally I got the "could not find class" error, which was removed after adding the cordova.js again. I'm stumped? Thanks in advance!

Comment: (I cannot comment in the other question).. But, you are subscribing to offline and online 2 times. Delete these to lines: **document.addEventListener("offline", this.onReceivedOffline, false);
    document.addEventListener("online", this.onReceivedOnline, false);**

Comment: ooops! such a simple overlook!! Thanks again you've been a great help Morten OC